# Cast ObjectiveC int and swift Int (Call Swift method from Objective-c with variables)

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am calling Swift function from ObjectiveC

These are my simple code

in my objective C Code

```
// mySwift class is put in delegate
[delegate testFunc]; // works well
int now = 10;
[delegate showCount:now]; //compile error
```

in my swift code

```
class mySwift {
    func showCount(nowpos: Int){
       // my code
    }
    func testFunc(){
       // it works well
    }
```

I can't compile this with this message.

```
myObjC.m:171:19: No known instance method for selector 'showCount:'
```

If I don't use variable(Make testfunction without variable), it works well.

I guess it is because of Type (Int, and int)

How can I slove this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about

> If I don't use the variable(Make test function without variable), it works
>   well.

But let's learn about why?

In Swift the function parameters have two parts i.e. `label` and `parameter`.

```
 func showCount(nowPostion nowpos: Int) {}
```

In above function the label is `nowPosition` and `nowpos` is the `paramater`. The use of this differentiation is that `label` is used by function caller where as `parameter` is used inside the function.

```
     showCount(nowPostion: 50) // calling function using label
```

But if I don't provide the `label` then the `parameter` is considered as the `labe`l and so when you are calling the function from Objective-C, it is not able to find this method.

```
    [delegate showCount:now];
```

Also, in Objective-C there is no way to provide `parameter` name in a method call. So, we will have to adjust this in Swift definition using `_`.

```
   func showCount(_ nowpos: Int)
```

The above definition says there is no `label` required while calling this function.

```
   func showCount(50) // This will work now
```

There are few caveats while working with Objective-C and Swift interop.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!!!! if I add '_', I can use Objective-c like variables

Comment: Yes. `_` will remove the need to add parameter name while calling the swift function from Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

Don't name the first parameter of your swift method `func showCount(nowpos: Int)` by using `_`.

Like this

```
class SwiftClass:NSObject {
    public func showCount(_ nowpos: Int){
        // my code
    }
    func testFunc(){
        // it works well
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this

```
class mySwift {
   class func showCount(nowpos: Int){
       // my code
    }

// calling
myswift.showcount(nowpos:5)
```

error is beacuse you are using the method without creating an instance of class,  and the example i wrote is of class method in which we dont require instance to call a class method